# Q: Freeform - have users update form on the frontend

Tags: plugin-freeform, solspace

I was wondering if it is possible to have users update their own entry on the front end with the [Solspace Freeform](https://solspace.com/craft/freeform) plugin.

I get as far as getting all the necessary data of the user (`freeform.submission`) in a form (`freeform.form`) and I have added an `input` with the `id` of the entry to the form:
 
`<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{submission.id}}" />`

When submitting this form it will save the data, but as a new entry instead of updating the existing one. So is there a way to update the existing `id`, similar as to what is happening in the cp?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to find a solution. It's probably not the best way to go, but it works.

In the form add a new action: `<input type="hidden" name="action" value="freeform/submissions/save">` which will override the standard action. It's the same form action Freeform uses to save entries in the CP.

Then add the `id` you want to update as `value=`. 
For example:
`<input type="hidden" name="submissionId" value="{{submission.id}}" />`

One disadvantage is, is that this POST does not support the handle, values,.. `input` data for the fields - you need to use the fields `id`. 
So 
`<input name="{{ firstName.handle }}" value="{{ firstName.value }}" >` 
becomes 
`<input name="field_1" value="{{submission.FirstName}}" />`

You can find the field `id` in the CP. Some fields might need a bit more info, like email is `field_3[]`.

Comment: This is not works with current freeform pro for anonymous user. Any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to edit a form in the front-end then you can do so by adding the following hidden inputs inside the form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="freeform/submissions/save">
<input type="hidden" name="submissionId" value="{{ submission.id }}">
<input type="hidden" name="statusId" value="{{ submission.statusId }}">
```

The controller we are reaching with this action requires you to post the submissionId and the statusId of the form.

To update a certain field of the form you have to give it the handle as name of the input like below:

```
<input type="text" name="{{ field.handle }}" value="new value">
```

One thing to keep in mind is that you will **ALWAYS** have to post all the fields with the request. If you don't then only the sent field will be filled in and the rest will get reset.